# What browsers have a hard time with File upload with Ajax & iframe?

Tags: ajax, browser, iframe, compatibility

I am considering using Ajax and iframes for a File Upload feature but I am concerned about potential incompatibilities with recent versions of the 5 or 6 major browsers. Any thought on that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some information that I found on a couple of sites...

---

[**AJAX**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_browser_support.htm)

All the available browsers can not support AJAX. Here is the list of major browsers which support AJAX.

- Mozilla Firefox 1.0 and above
- Netscape version 7.1 and above
- Apple Safari 1.2 and above.
- Microsoft Internet Exporer 5 and above
- Konqueror
- Opera 7.6 and above

**NOTE**

Refer to the link provided for a tutorial on how to write browser specific code through the use of `try/catch` blocks.

---

[**IFRAME** for HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) and [**IFRAME** for HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_iframe.asp)

HTML `<iframe>` and HTML5 `<iframe>` is supported on all major browsers (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome, and Safari)

---

In other words, you shouldn't have any problems with what you're trying to do :D

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your response. iframes seem to be the right thing for what I want to do. Regards